# Symfony 6 : how to manage multi role hierarchies

Tags: php, symfony

I followed the documentation to have a [multi entity manager/multi db app](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)
But for each DB there is specfic roles, and I don't know how to achieve this.

I symply tried to import a `security.yaml` file based on the current `db` (for each db I load an `.env` file), but it seem we can't use environment variable to import anything in yaml file. Example :

> // security.yaml
>
> imports:
> - { resource: 'custom/%env(SPECIFIC_SECURITY_YAML)%' }

> // .envFoo
>
> SPECIFIC_SECURITY_YAML=teachers.yaml

> // .envBar
>
> SPECIFIC_SECURITY_YAML=sellers.yaml

And in each `teachers.yaml` and `sellers.yaml` there are all `security_yaml` related parameters + `role_hierarchy` and `access_control`

The other solution is to symply store the role in the db, but I lose the role hierarchy, and I have to manually chose each role.

Do you have an idea? I don't know why the symfony doc doesn't explain how to do this if symfony allows us to have multi db app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing the roles in database then created a `Profil` entity to manage the roles. I keep the `Role_hierarchy` as it is